# How to force ojet to install node-sass version 4.9 instead of the default version (4.7)?

Tags: javascript, oracle

I am following the book "Practical Oracle JET". where I am asked to execute the following command.

```
ojet add sass
```

I get error in the log.

I am using windows server 2008r2 64
oracle jet version 6
Node version 10.16.1
NPM version 6.9

The error log I get :
  **verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`**

After a lot of search I realized that nod-sass@4.7.2 is not compatible with node 10. So I need to make oracle jet uses version 4.9 as the default version.

I found the file "\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@oracle\ojet-cli\node_modules@oracle\generator-oraclejet\package.json"
and replaced the version number as required, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing the node-sass library manually (outside of the JET CLI command.  Once the node-sass library is installed, you can then go back and run ojet add sass to get the rest of the parts installed.

from the root of your project:

npm install node-sass

--jb